# Logo not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, graphical-logo

Some time ago I installed a theme for my blog. It was really good and had almost all features I wanted but now I came to know that it has a small bug that there is no place to upload the site logo. I have tried my very best looking into the framework and the child theme but was unable to find any option to upload the logo image(It does have a option which asks the user if he or she wants to display text logo or image logo).

### Description of the theme

The theme is divided in to two parts the framework and the child theme.

---

> header.php

---

```
<?php
/**
 * WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 * this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 * in the form of a child theme.
 *
 * Handles the header structure.
 *
 * @package Genesis
 */
do_action( 'genesis_doctype' );

do_action( 'genesis_title' );

do_action( 'genesis_meta' );

wp_head(); /** we need this for plugins **/
?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
do_action( 'genesis_before' );
?>
<div id="wrap">
<?php
do_action( 'genesis_before_header' );
do_action( 'genesis_header' );
do_action( 'genesis_after_header' );

echo '<div id="inner">';
genesis_structural_wrap( 'inner' );
```

---

> functions.php

---

```
<?php
/**
 * WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 * this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 * in the form of a child theme.
 *
 * This file calls the init.php file, but only
 * if the child theme hasn't called it first.
 *
 * This method allows the child theme to load
 * the framework so it can use the framework
 * components immediately.
 *
 * @package Genesis
 */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/init.php' );
```

Please help me out with it. Thanks

Comment: "no place to upload the site logo" -- does this help? http://www.magnet4marketing.net/2010/12/18/how-to-add-custom-header-logo-to-studiopress-premium-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the Genesis framework author. If it's a theme framework, I would have thought they'd be a theme option somewhere (possible under 'Appearance' in wp-admin) to upload a logo image.

Comment: Yes they is an option to select theme or text in the header but no area to upload the logo image. I have checked many times.

Comment: So what image does get displayed if you select 'image' as the logo type (text or image)?

Comment: There is no option to upload the image. If I select image for logo option then it displays blank area there(No image gets displayed). I even tried uploading a image using FileZilla but still that did not helped.

Comment: Have you got the URL of your website?

Comment: Check out the '[Genesis for Beginners User Manual (PDF format)](http://www.studiopress.com/download/genesis-for-beginners-v10.pdf)' link at http://www.studiopress.com/tutorials. Chapter 7 goes into details on the header/logo, so follow that based on your current setup.